# How to play audio received in didOutputSampleBuffer:?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, avcapturesession, avqueueplayer

I am working on conference related application, i have first capture audio with CaptureSession, now I want to play the audio data dynamically without saving into file. I have tried with `AVQueue` it seems both `CaptureSession` and `AVQueue` won't work together when I starts queue it stops capture, so What can I do now to play audio captured through CaptureSession?

thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem using AudioUnit method, Note: when we process audio data captured in AVCapturesession using AudioUnit, we need to ensure AudioUnit is not trying to access capture devices (Mic in my case), that is the reason it stopped capture call back.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `convert` your `audioData` into `NSData`:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer: (CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

  NSData *audioData = yourFunction here to convert//[self audioFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSError *e;
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&e];
    NSLog(@"%@",[e description]);
    [player setDelegate:self];
    [player play];
  }
}
```

**EDIT** : refer [Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_4%29) link.

Comment: hi prince, did you tried this way? worked? Can you please tell me which way you converted sampleBuffer to NSData.

Comment: that link they are playing using file, But I want to play the raw data as it is received.